# Android - cache spring pojo objects in sqlite database

Tags: android, spring, rest, ormlite, pojo

Curtently, my app loads some data from rest webservice, using spring's RestTemplate and java pojo classes with Jackson.
So as a result, I have java objects, containing data retrieved from webservice.

But I also need to have my data available for offline use. So my idea is to save data to sqlite database. Can I use my pojo classes as a models for ormlite to save/load data?

I want to directly save my data to sqlite, using pojo class objects that I already have as ormlite models, is it possible with ormlite? Note that my pojo classes contain fields declared as other pojo object, so probably there will be   needed some table structure with foreign keys. Can it be handled automatically by ormlite?

Answer (score 0):

You have to annotate your POJO Model with proper ormlite annotations @DatabaseTable and @DatabaseColumn.

Nextly you have to build up a class(eg. OrmDatabaseHelper)  that extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper;

Afterwards you can inject object like this

```
@OrmLiteDao(helper = OrmDatabaseHelper.class)
Dao<YourCustomPOJO, Long> yourCustomDao;
```

Long stands for the ID field type.
This allows you to use dao's methods like create, delete, queryForAll etc.

```
YourCustomPOJO pojo = new YourCustomPOJO();
//set some values
yourCustomDao.create(pojo);
```